# CSS: size element height to x% of the screen

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if there's a way to set the css with an `x` (unknown) percentage amount, like `height: *%;`? In the case that it is not possible, how to make it take the size of the rest of the screen?

I tried in http://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/xnau2wsL/ and http://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/xnau2wsL/1/ but in this fiddle these `div` elements are not even taking the desired screen height size, let alone the goal of using the whole screen all together.

**HTML**

```
<div id="hello">Hello</div>
<div id="world">world</div>
<div id="shout">!</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#hello {
    border: solid black 2px;
    min-height: 10%;
}
#shout {
    border: solid brown 2px;
    /*inherit height from content*/
}
#world {
    border: solid blue 4px;
    height: *;
}
```

By the way, I do not want to set a height with pixels and overflow since I'd like to have a mobile friendly (RWD) css

**Notes**

- **Height size for `#hello` is known `10%` media (screen) size**
- Height size for `#shout` is not known (inherited from the content)
- Height size for `#world` is the rest of the media (`x%`)
- Can it be done **without changing the semantics**? -No container or changes, just css

Comment: I dont understand, do you want that divs to be 33.33% of the height of the screen each?

Comment: Thought the same but thinking 33,333333% sometimes this makes it smoother.. ;)

Comment: `height: calc(100% / 3);`

Comment: @user3597089 I never said to have all elements to use the whole screen. Each element has a "specific" size that **together** must use the whole media (screen). Check my updates and notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does display:table would do :

```css
html,body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  }
body {
  display:table;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  }
body>div {
display:table-row;
  }
#hello {
  height:10%;
  border:green solid;
  }
#world {
  border:solid purple;  
  }
#shout:hover {
  height:15%;
  }
#shout {
  height:1%;
  border:red solid;
  }
```

```html
<div id="hello">Hello</div>
<div id="world">world</div>
<div id="shout">!,hover me to make me grow</div>
```

or better display:flex;

```css
html,body {
  height:100%;
  }
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin:0;
  }
#hello {
  height:10%;
  border:green solid;
  }
#world {
  border:solid purple;  
  flex:1
  }
#shout { 
;
  border:red solid;
  }
#shout:hover {
  height:25%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="hello">Hello</div>
<div id="world">world</div>
<div id="shout">!, hover me to make me grow</div>
```

Comment: I am curious, why is `flex` better than `display:table` like you mentioned?  =)

Comment: @Omar because it has no sides effect that might require some extra markup. with empty div it seems quiet perfect

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the divs take to a height using percentage, the container surrounding the divs has to have a set height in the css: http://jsfiddle.net/xwyg89jk/

If the container is the body tag, you can set:

```
html {
height: 100%;
}

body {
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You can add to this that you can make it more preccise by using the `calc` CSS function. Just use `width: calc(100% / 3);` instead of `width: 33%.`

Comment: Something surrounding it has to have a height for it to know what to be "10%" of. What I was saying with the `body` and `html` tags is to set those at `height: 100%` so you're giving your divs a set height to work with. http://jsfiddle.net/s3kqt0ey/

Answer (score 1):

**The percentage is base on parent's height**, so you must have a parent with height.

You need to add  `height: 100%; position: absolute;` on the wrapper:

```css
#hello {
    border: solid black 2px;
    min-height: 10%;
}
#shout {
    border: solid brown 2px;
}
#world {
    border: solid blue 4px;
    height: 70%;

}
#wrap{
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <h1>Size and unit % wildcard</h1>
    <div id="hello">Hello</div>
    <div id="world">world</div>
    <div id="shout">!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you do it without a  breaking the semantic ("container")?